# How to make sharepoint webpart deployment faster?

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I am using Windows server 2003 OS.I have built SharePoint webparts in VS2010 for SharePoint 2007.Each time I deploy from the WSP project it takes few minutes to deploy it to the SharePoint site. This is considerably annoying since each time when the webpart code is changes it will take lot of time to deploy. It become very hard for the development and testing purpose.Can anyone suggest if there is any way to make the deployment faster?

Thank you

Comment: I am not using any Deployment script. I am using a WSP builder Project to deploy the webpart in SharePoint. Deployment across the farm takes longer time. Can you suggest me with any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider [deploying your web part to the bin](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263271%28office.12%29.aspx) during your dev process (using a post build xcopy or something similar).  It'll speed you up massively.  You'll still need to test your WSP deployment.